# symfony 2.7 twig not updating changes

Tags: twig, symfony-2.7

I'm dealing with a interesting issue that I haven't encountered before.

I'm trying to fix an ex-employees old issue in symfony2.7. However the twig file is not updating the changes that were made. The cache has been disabled and the folder isn't being created. But it still won't update. I have even ran `php app/console cache:clear --env prod` or  `php app/console cc --env prod` it runs successfully but there still isn't any changes. I have tried restarting `apache2 service` but no change.

file location is under `app/resources/views/admin.nav.menu.html.twig`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

os is Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue. There was multiple instances running on different servers.